# How to alias Vuex Actions globally, when called from within a Vuex module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm essentially looking for the proper syntax in Vue 2 to create Vuex methods that can be accessed globally, but are located within a module. The convention I usually see for this uses the `$` character, such as `$axios` or `$store`.

On instantiation of the Vue instance, I can do things like importing Axios and then applying the instance like so:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

export default (state) => {
    Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;
}
```

What I would like to do is similar to this, but I want to access a custom Vuex module I have created. Let's say my module has actions that handle authentication, and the module is named `auth`. And lets say one of these actions is the `logout` action. I can call the this action in my Vue components like so:

```js
this.$store.dispatch("auth/logout");
```

But instead of this, I want to be able to simply do

```
this.$auth.logout()
```

or something similarly concise.

It seems that it's not possible to simply do something like

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

export default (state) => {
    Vue.prototype.$auth.logout = state.store.dispatch("auth/LOGOUT");
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
// src/plugins/auth.js
import Vue from "vue";
import store from "../store";

Vue.prototype.$auth = {
  login() {
    store.dispatch("auth/LOGIN");
  },
  logout() {
    store.dispatch("auth/LOGOUT");
  }
};
```

And in your main.js just add the import to this file:

```
// src/main.js
// imports...
import "./plugins/auth.js";
// code...
```

You can use it like this:

```
// src/components/Test.vue
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    this.$auth.login()
  }
}
</script>
```

Example source code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-forked-pl01u

Comment: It is possible you have setted it in another place or you have a third-party package setting this `auth` property. For more information on Vue instance properties, check this [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html)

Comment: Quite so - it seems that `$auth` cannot be used, perhaps because it is the name of the Vuex module... Any other variable is fine. Thanks!